# How to stop an Arduino Servo from moving during the myservo.attach() command

Tags: arduino, servo

I'm using the default Servo library in Arduino. When my Arduino Uno starts up and it attaches the servo the motor will move a good portion of its range. I can't have this happen for my project, I need it to turn and stay in its current position.

Also I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26695670/attach-arduino-servo-without-moving) post but if I am reading it correctly its for a different library.

Comment: Welcome to SO, how to help you with only "default Servo library in Arduino"... Please read again ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to provide ["a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: "a good portion of its range"? what does that mean? 20%? 50%? what is its range? will it always move to the same position? this sentence says nothing.

Answer (score 4):

**Why the problem occurs?**

RC servos set their position accordingly to width of a pulses sent to them. Usually this width changes in range of ~500 - 2500us, with a frequency of 50Hz. When a servo receives such a signal, it goes to a corresponding position. For example - if it receives pulses 1500us wide, it would go to middle position. When you invoke `servo.attach()`, Arduino will start sensing pulses of `DEFAULT_PULSE_WIDTH` which happens to be 1500us.

**What can be done about that?**

The solution from the linked question applies also to standard Arduino servo library. Find `DEFAULT_PULSE_WIDTH` and change it's value to 0. If there are no pulses, the servo won't turn. Arduino will start sending signal after first `servo.write()` call. Remember, that there will be no holding torque until that time.

Comment: @King if you are wondering what is going on in a library just read its source code. In my case its in C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\Servo\ for the given problem. you have the source code and it is up to you to read, understand and if needed modify it. its a computer, your very own, willingless slave. become it's master!

Comment: @Piglet which source file would you change, specifically, in your Servo folder? Do you know how many `Servo.cpp` source files are in that folder?

Comment: @neuronet you cannot have more than one `Servo.cpp` in the same folder... and you change the file that contains the particular thing you want to change. I really don't get what you want. please be more specific

Answer (score 0):

**Possible cause**

When your Arduino Uno starts up two things are going on at the same time

- Arduino Uno runs it's bootloader and servo pin is in input mode
- Servo gets power and moves a bit while getting no signal

After bootloader finished your, program starts and call to attach is perfomred.

I could reproduce the effect with my Arduino starter kid and its includes cheap servo.